# Pushing Vertical Scrollbar to Bottom Of div as Item added

Tags: jquery, css, dom, scrollbar

Can you please take a look at [THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/5cuGg/3/) and following code and let me know how I can keep the vertical Scrollbar at the bottom (displaying latest added content- items)

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<button id="append">Add Item</button>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#append").click(function () {
        $('ul').append('<li>New Item</li>');
        $('div').animate({
            scrollDown: $('div').attr(20)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: take a look at this SO, this should serve your purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('div').animate({
    scrollTop: $('div')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000
);
```

The demo http://jsfiddle.net/5cuGg/7/

Comment: Glad to help you ... try to make more specific your selector later in your web with an id or classname to keep more control